# laravel composer update : the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I am using ubuntu 16.04, laravel 5.2
when i run update composer in my project directory its showing 
"the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system"
i checked installed packages of PHP, its available there

Comment: Check `php -m` listing

Answer (score 184):

Installing xml-extension (php7.0-xml in my case) solved the problem

```
sudo apt-get install php-xml
```

Comment: Saved my time too!

Comment: You saved me too.

Answer (score 35):

If PHP version is 7.2, execute the following command

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2-xml
```

Answer (score 11):

### **Managed to fix it with a php version 5.6* :**

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install php5.6-xml
```

Answer (score 11):

You might have some missing dependencies, so first run

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Then install php-xml

```
sudo apt-get install php-xml
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 10):

DOM is a PHP extension and not a PHP package. This means that your version of PHP needs to be recompiled with the extension. It is possible however that your PHP was already compiled with DOM but that DOM is not enabled.
You can check this in your php.ini (search for `extension=dom.so` and make sure it's uncommented).

Answer (score 8):

In my case I use

> sudo apt-get update

and

> sudo apt-get install php7.3-xml

Comment: for Centos: `yum install php7.3-xml`