# Errors in Laravel Creating Project

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

i am new with laravel
i installed composer and laravel in my ubuntu
but when i insert  `composer create-project laravel/laravel {projectname}` to create project 
these errors shows me

```
 Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - phpunit/phpunit 7.5.x-dev requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 7.5.1 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 7.5.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 7.4.5 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 7.4.4 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 7.4.3 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 7.4.2 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 7.4.1 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 7.4.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 7.3.5 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 7.3.4 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 7.3.3 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 7.3.2 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 7.3.1 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 7.3.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 7.2.7 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 7.2.6 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 7.2.5 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 7.2.4 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 7.2.3 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 7.2.2 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 7.2.1 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 7.2.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 7.1.5 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 7.1.4 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 7.1.3 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 7.1.2 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 7.1.1 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 7.1.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 7.0.3 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 7.0.2 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 7.0.1 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 7.0.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for phpunit/phpunit ^7.0 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[7.0.0, 7.0.1, 7.0.2, 7.0.3, 7.1.0, 7.1.1, 7.1.2, 7.1.3, 7.1.4, 7.1.5, 7.2.0, 7.2.1, 7.2.2, 7.2.3, 7.2.4, 7.2.5, 7.2.6, 7.2.7, 7.3.0, 7.3.1, 7.3.2, 7.3.3, 7.3.4, 7.3.5, 7.4.0, 7.4.1, 7.4.2, 7.4.3, 7.4.4, 7.4.5, 7.5.0, 7.5.1, 7.5.x-dev].
```

i searched my this question on google but i could not find any useful thing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [laravel composer update : the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37873482/laravel-composer-update-the-requested-php-extension-dom-is-missing-from-your-s)

Answer (score 2):

You should install the php-xml in order to make this happen.

```
sudo apt-get install php-xml
```

this will install the php-xml (depends on what version of php you're using). I think you can also do the following:

`sudo apt-get install php7.0-xml`

Comment: gave me the error that there is no package like this